# R missing levels in a model.matrix

Tags: r, model.matrix

I am trying to convert a data frame with categorical variables to a model.matrix but am losing levels of variables.

Here's my code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:200, y =rbinom(200, 1, .5),  var1 = factor(rep(c('abc','def','ghi','jkl'),50)))
df1$var2 <- factor(rep(c('ab c','ghi','jkl','def'),50))
df1$var3 <- factor(rep(c('abc','ghi','nop','xyz'),50))

df1$var2 <- as.character(df1$var2)
df1$var2 <- gsub('\\s','',df1$var2)
df1$var2 <- factor(df1$var2)
sapply(df1, levels)

mm1 <- model.matrix(~ 0+.,df1)
head(mm1)
```

Any suggestions? Is this a matrix non-invertability issue?

Comment: This is a representation issue. Matrices in R do not retain attributes of their input data and that happens to be where factors store their character-values.

Comment: I should add that if you are creating a model matrix from factors that you should see an expansion of the number of columns that should represent the various factor levels correctly. In your instance that would mean that for var2, the "abc" level will be considered separately from the "abc" level in var3. Each level other than the reference level will get it's own column of 1's 1nd 0's.

Answer (score 6):

The model matrix is perfectly correct. For factors, the model matrix contains one column less than there are factors: this information is already contained in the `(Intercept)` column. You are missing this column because you have specified `+0` in your model term. Try this:

```
mm2 <- model.matrix(~., df1)
head(mm2)
```

You will now see the `(Intercept)` column which encodes "default" information, and now also the first level of `var1` is missing in the column names. The `(Intercept)` represents your observation at the "reference level", which is the combination of first level of each categorical attribute. Any deviation from this reference level is encoded in the `var*???` columns, and since your model assumes no interactions between these columns, you get (4 - 1) * 3 `var*???` columns plus the `(Intercept)` column (which is replaced by `var1abc` in your initial model matrix).

Unfortunately I lack the precise terms to describe this. Anyone help me out?